# Add Custom HTML Tag by Editing DTD

Tags: javascript, html, tags, dtd

[Sample DTD](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd)

The above is a link points to `strict.dtd` file in w3.org. It contain definition for HTML4 Tags. I want to know that whether it is possible to create my own HTML tag by just editing the `DTD` (should supported by latest version of all major browsers (eg : chrome/ff/edge)). I found many articles and solutions on creating custom Tags even in stackoverflow. But it make use of JavaScript to create a tag. I want to make it by editing DTD.
for example :

```
<custom-tag property=value></custom-tag>
```

I don't want to achieve this using `data-*` in HTML5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers don’t read DTDs or do anything with them. They never have. So no point to make a DTD.

Instead if you want to use `<custom-tag property=value></custom-tag>`
in your HTML, just do it.

The [W3C HTML Checker (validator) will not report an error for it](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%3C%2521DOCTYPE%2520html%3E%250D%250A%3Ctitle%3ETest%3C%252Ftitle%3E%250D%250A%3Ccustom-tag%2520property%253Dvalue%3E%3C%252Fcustom-tag%3E#textarea), because it recognizes all element with names containing a hyphen as being custom elements.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of including DTD in webpages?

Comment: There is no purpose of including a DTDs in webpages. DTDs are just cruft of the SGML legacy from which HTML arose. That’s why these days you can and should just put a `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype on your documents, rather than an HTML4 doctype or anything else that references a DTD.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use/"create" yours owns TAGs as by example:

```
<city>Barcelona</city>
<brand>My Company</brand>
```

then use XHTML and add yours tags to your own DTD:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_intro.asp